# APScheduler store job in custom database of mongodb

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, apscheduler

I want to store the job in mongodb using python and it should schedule on specific time.

I did googling and found APScheduler will do. i downloaded the code and tried to run the code.

It's schedule the job correctly and run it, but it store the job in apscheduler database of mongodb, i want to store the job in my own database.

Can please tell me how to store the job in my own database instead of default db.

Answer (score 1):

Simply give the mongodb jobstore a different "database" argument. It seems like the API documentation for this job store was not included in what is available on ReadTheDocs, but you can inspect the source and see how it works.